# can't pass variables to pug/jade template with node email templates

Tags: node.js, templates, pug, email-templates

I'm trying to render a pug/jade template with node email templates.

```
                var confirmCode = generateConfirmCode(configPublic.confirmCodeLength);
                var query = querystring.stringify({
                    code: confirmCode,
                    id: user._id.toString()
                });

                var templateDir = path.join(__dirname, '../templates', 'confirmation-email');
                var confirmEmail = new EmailTemplate(templateDir);
                var confirmUrl = configPublic.url + '/user/email/confirm?' + query;
                var templateVals = {url: confirmUrl};

                confirmEmail.render(templateVals, function(err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    var mailOptions = {
                        from: configPrivate.gmail.username,
                        to: user.email.address,
                        subject: 'confirmation',
                        html: result.html
                    };
                    email.send(mailOptions)
                        .then(function (successMsg) {
                            db.setConfirmCode(user, confirmCode)
                                .catch(function (err) { // catch setConfirmCode err
                                    deferred.reject(err);
                                });
                            deferred.resolve(successMsg);
                        })
                        .catch(function (err) { // catch send err
                            deferred.reject(err);
                        })
```

So I pass `templateVals` to the render call, and I'm trying to figure out how to display that information on the rendered template like so:

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='./style.css')
|
|
p !{url}
p #{url}
p url
p templateVals.url
p #{templateVals.url}
p !{templateVals.url}
```

and none of these combinations seem to be working. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up not being an issue with the code, but with the webstorm file watcher putting an html file in the `email-templates` template directory causing the render to fail